# Why OpenZeppelin's address.sol says that plain call is unsafe in solidity

Tags: security, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I'm studying about ERC20.sol of OpenZeppelin. As Address.sol is imported, I looked at it and most of the default functions are wrapped(?) or re-declared.

Also, I saw the comment that plain `call` is an unsafe replacement for a function call. Then we should avoid using `call` function and import Address.sol and use `functionCall` in our codes?

So my question is

1. Why OpenZeppelin is wrapping the default functions.
2. Is plain `call` function should be avoided? and Why?
3. Insead of `call` function, should we use `functionCall` from Address.sol?

Answer (score 1):

The low-level native `call()` is a safe and slightly cheaper gas-wise - if you know what you're doing.

The OpenZeppelin `functionCall()` wraps the native `call()` and provides validations on top of that. For example it reverts with a custom message if you're calling a non-contract address or sending along more `value` than your contract owns. So simply said, it's more developer friendly.